# replace html tag in html editor with specific string

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

hi anyone knows how to replace a html tag in a string  with specific characters:
 e.g.

```
string s1 =  "<span style="italic">inluding <span style="bold">other</span> tags </span>";
string s2 =  "<span style="italic">inluding </span><span style="bold">other tags </span>";
```

i want to replace "span" with "bold" to "bOpen" and "bClose" and to replace "span" with "italic" to "iOpen" and "iClose" in both c# and javascript.
thanks very much.

thanks for the response, i did use regular expression to do that: res = Regex.Replace(res, ".*?", replaceHtmlBold); but it cant match the nested tag and none-nested tag at the same time. could you help please?

Comment: Are you asking to create invalid HTML?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: i jsut want to replace tags including open and close pair with predefined customized ones,thanks

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-replace.php)'s String Object has a handy function that lets you replace words that occur within the string. So does [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are your friends here. I could give you the exact code for your problem, but then you'll miss the point of learning this technique. Here is an [Introduction to Regular Expressions](http://devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=523) and there is this article ["C# Regular Expressions"](http://oreilly.com/windows/archive/csharp-regular-expressions.html). If you need more, Google is your friend.

Good luck!

PS: I realized now what the real problem is. I think you can get away with [lookaround techniques](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [conditionals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html). Both are summarized [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html).

Comment: thanks for the response, 
i did use regular expression to do that:
res = Regex.Replace(res, "<span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">.*?</span>", replaceHtmlBold);
but it cant match the nested tag and none-nested tag at the same time. could you help please?

Comment: I have added some comments above. Now I have to go home. I'll think about it and tell you later.